# Automatically changing js calendar

Tags: javascript, function, calendar

I have written a calendar in basic html, then placed it into a array in my js, which will use the menuchange.innerHTML. Based on the getMonth method the calendar (calendars actually) will switch based on the month. My problem is that my function is coming back undefined, it's a semantic error, and neither my friends nor I can figure out the error. I'm sorry if this seems extremely simple, but I'm a beginner, thank you for all your help!

```
  month = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMonth(); 
        console.log(n);
    }
    month();
```

All of my month functions are also coming back undefined, once again, all my syntax is correct

```
    showJanuary = function () {
menuchange.innerHTML = [
'...........................',
'...........................',
'...........................',
'...........................',
]
.join("\n"); 
}
```

Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Works fine for me (in a firefox scratchpad), perhaps the problem lies somewhere else in your code or in your browser/exec environment. If you're using it as an argument somewhere else then that's expected (there's no return in the function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're expecting your functions to return a value. I'm guessing your month function probably logs the correct month, but you'll need a return statement for your code to be able to do something with that value:

```
month = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth(); 
    return n;
}

var thisMonth = month(); // thisMonth is now the current month
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Feel free to mark the answer as correct (just click the checkmark to the left). That's even better than an upvote.